# partially applying arguments without declaring a new function

Tags: javascript, apply

Let's say I have the following functions:

```
function needR(){
...
}
(function init (r) {
...
})();
```

Please assume that init can be either an anonymous self executing function or not, it is really not important, I think...
Is it possible to apply r to needR from init without creating a new function from it?

I was just curious then did some searches but found nothing, so I am assuming this is not achievable not just not practical. But I wanted to be sure.

Thanks,

Comment: Declare ```var r;``` at the outside of any of the functions and manipulate ```r``` at ```init()```.

Comment: you mean `bind` without `bind` ??

Comment: If that is true, we dont needed bind :-D

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). So I'll suggest binding the argument. Though this technically does 'create a new function' which you wanted to not do, I assume you actually meant without the developer explicitly defining a new function.

```js
let sum = (a, b) => a + b;

let add5 = sum.bind(null, 5); // this is a new function

console.log(add5(3)); // 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think I explained what I was trying to achieve right, but my question is pretty clear.

The way you are doing works fine but, yes that is what I wanted to avoid. Thanks for taking the time to craft a fine answer.